# Select records by first row and page size

Tags: pagination, mybatis

I'm trying to implement lazy loading and pagination in my front end. I've been supplied the following two variables by the front end:

- `firstRow` - the index of the first record to return in results of the select query.
- `pageSize` - the total size of the records which the select query must return, starting at `firstRow`.

How can I use them in a select query in MyBatis in order to return the desired subset of records?

Comment: The principle is just the same as in JPA/Hibernate/whatever. Just let MyBatis fire a SQL query which returns exactly the subset of records starting with `first` and having a size of `pageSize` which are as arguments provided to you in `LazyDataModel#load()` method. That's all. The problem is most definitely not in JSF/PrimeFaces side. I suggest to reframe the question to omit the JSF/PrimeFaces noise (which is irrelevant and potentially confusing to MyBatis users) and re-ask how to fire a `LIMIT`/`OFFSET` SQL query in MyBatis based on 2 variables holding the first index and the result size.

Comment: @BalusC thank you, I edited my question, it's the first time I'm face to face with lazy loading  so I don't really know anything and I can't find any real implementations with mybatis (not yet, at least). Will keep looking

Comment: Still not good. I reformulated your question.

Comment: @BalusC ok, sounds way better then my version... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not really any magic to pagination in mybatis just write the query then subset it using row number. Pagination syntax will vary depending on the database, but here is an oracle example.

```
select *
from (
  select r.*, rownum rnum,
  from (# base query goes here #) r
)
where rnum >= (#{firstRow}) 
and rnum < #{firstRow} + #{pageSize}
```

Comment: <select id="getWithLimitRaspunsPozitii" parameterType="java.util.Map"
  resultMap="RPMap">
  SELECT * FROM
  (
  SELECT t.*, Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY
  NR_CURENT) MyRow
  FROM
  table t
  )
  WHERE MyRow
  BETWEEN
  #{offset} AND
  #{limit}

 </select> I'm using this at the moment but it's pretty slow, do you think your query would be more efficient?

Comment: They are essentially the same thing. You are explicitly using a row_number function over an ordered partition. I am using Oracle's rownum pseudo column and letting the optimizer determine how to best implement the sort and window which should result in the same execution plan.